# Routing with express and consign in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to implement routing in my Express app which is to be exposed through a cloud function.

Here is my functions/index.js file :

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const consign = require('consign');

const app = express();

  consign()
    .include("./routes")
    .into(app);

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

This is my ./routes/index.js file

```
module.exports = app => {
    app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.json({status:"success"});
})
}
```

So I guess this code is enough to host a cloud function and when I call this hosting url  https://us-central1-appname-79516.cloudfunctions.net/api (url changed for reason of privacy) it should return response as {"status":"success":}

Instead when I call the above url it displays the error "Error: could not handle the request"

Help me how to use express and consign module in a cloud function

Comment: Have you tried to host an express app without consign to see if that works first?

Comment: Yes it worked!!

Comment: So you're saying that the moment you add consign to the same app, there is a problem?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but still relevant I guess. So, this is what I've done:

```
consign({
  cwd: 'src'
})
.include("routes")
.into(app)
```

CWD sets the base directory, as stated on the docs:

`Consign will simply use a relative path from your current working directory, however, sometimes you don't want heavily nested files included in the object chain, so you can set the cwd`

https://github.com/jarradseers/consign

In my case, `src` is the folder containing my firebase functions code (functions/src).

Hope it helps!